# How to convert array of objects from string to normal array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have array of objects in string format I want to convert it into normal array of objects. I have used `JSON.parse()` to convert it but when I am trying to get the value like: `this.contact_data[0].data.value` it shows undefined.

It's my array of objects:

```js
contact_data.data='[{'name':"Number",'value':"22222222"},{'name':"gmail",'value':"xyz@gamil.com"}]'
```

Comment: that's not an array of anything, it's invalid and won't parse

Comment: that is a string. Anything inside a single quotes or double quotes is a string

Comment: except the way it's shown is not valid javascript and will throw an error

Comment: Where does this _"string"_ actually come from? What you've got in your question isn't even valid JS so it unlikely you've got anything like that

Comment: I think what you want to ask is 'How do I parse JSON to a JS object/array?', which you can't do in this case as that is not valid JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The key in the array of objects after stringify should be in double quotes like `"` but this is in single quotes `'` that's why it will not parse

`'[{"name":"Number","value":"22222222"},{"name":"gmail","value":"xyz@gamil.com"}]'`
this is correct stringify array which will parse

`'[{'name':"Number",'value':"22222222"},{'name':"gmail",'value':"xyz@gamil.com"}]'`
and this is you array